Кастомная подцветка синтаксиса NVim
Я хочу сделать кастомную подыветку синтаксиса редактора. Я где-то нашел как это сделать:
~/.config/nvim/init.vim
:syn keyword Keyword class

Мне нужно чтоб я мог устанавливать свои цвета, жирность и тд, желательно в 16-ной системе.
Тоесть "Слово" : #hheexx.
Можно так сделать? Я нигде не нашел все стили кроме Keyword.
